# Idris: Is there a way to reference an abstracted variable in an equality proof?

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

The simplest example of the problem (but not the only example I can exhibit) is: suppose I'm given a higher order function `f : (a -> b) -> c`. I'd like to prove that `f = (\g => f (\x => g x))`.

In my own reasoning, it should be pretty straightforward: just apply eta-equivalence twice (once inside, and then outside).

If I wanted to prove `f = (\x => f x)`, a simple `Refl` would have sufficed: this led me to think that "Idris knows about eta-equivalence". But then again, the same solution didn't work for `f = (\g => f (\x => g x))`.

At that point, I tried using `rewrite`, but couldn't find a way to reference the `g` in `(\g => f (\x => g x))`:

```
lemma : {g : a -> b} -> g = (\x => g x)
lemma = Refl

theorem : {f : (a -> b) -> c} ->
          f = (\g => f (\x => g x))
theorem = rewrite (lemma {g = _}) in Refl
```

But, of course, Idris can't figure out what `_` should be, and neither do I.

This can be further reduced to the problem of proving `(\g => f g) = (\g => f (\x => g x))`, of course, because Idris knows equality is transitive and knows about eta-equivalence (at least when it's not "hidden" in lambda abstractions).

I'm starting to believe that what I'm experiencing is somehow happening because Idris doesn't know about extensionality: is there any other way of proving this (without tweaking the notion of equality I'm using, such as using setoids)?

I'm using Idris 1.3.2 from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can postulate extensionality:

```
postulate
funext : {f, g : a -> b} -> ((x : a) -> f x = g x) -> f = g

theorem : {f : (a -> b) -> c} -> f = (\g => f (\x => g x))
theorem = funext $ \g => Refl
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I did use extensionality elsewhere in the project this came from (but didn't know about "postulate", so I used "believe_me"). But I read somewhere that it can mess up the type system as soon as I rely on this kind of equality when working with a dependent type: isn't it the case?